# why can't I create jndi datasource for oracle 12c?

Tags: jdbc, oracle12c

This is the context.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/embmngdb_conn" auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="20" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000"
    username="c##empmngdb" password="123"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/oracle" />
```

This is the Employee_Controller_Servlet.java

```
private Employee_DB_Util employee_db_util;

@Resource(name = "jdbc/c##empmngdb")
private DataSource data_source;
```

My question is, where am I going wrong with this? The same thing worked for me in MySQL, why doesn't it work here? I changed the whole URL and everything, do I need driver manager when trying to acquire data source with oracle 12c? Help me out.

Error

```
oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

Comment: want to mention that    name="jdbc/embmngdb_conn"    embmngdb_conn is the name of the connection.

Comment: Have made the change that you mentioned, still error showing.
a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: got your point, edited that, but still not getting connected and showing a new error. Gonna attach that with question.

Comment: HTTP Status 500 - java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Listener refused the connection with the following error:
this is the actual error that's showing now.

Comment: Apparently the service name of your Oracle instance is something else than `oracle` (the last part in the URL). Only you can know which service name you specified during the installation.

Comment: Got the solution, changed the name to orcl, thanks a lot for your specific suggestions.